# Regarding configuration of a central, shared Git repository

Tags: git, ssh, msysgit, ssh-keys, repository

We've just started using Git in our workplace and though we're learning a lot using Git on our local systems, there's one thing that we haven't been able to do yet.

I want to create a repository on my system which should be accessible to other systems on my network for clone, pull, push etc. commands.

I read around and found out that here's what I need to do:

1.Create a bare repo on my system (say, System A) using the following command:

```
git init --bare --shared=all
```

2.Then, if I want the user on System B to have access to my repo on System A, here's what I need to do:

i.Generate a public-private key pair for the user on System B by running the following command on user B's gitbash:

```
ssh-keygen
```

ii.Copy user B's public key and paste it in my (i.e. System A) ~/.ssh folder. Suppose the name of user B's public key is userb.pub

***And this is where I'm stuck:***

iii.Add user B's public key (userb.pub) to the list of authorized keys on my system.

***But I can't find any file called authorized_keys in my ~/.ssh folder!***

And even if I created my own authorized_keys file, how would I add all of the public keys to it? In the same line? No separators? Would I need to add my own key (i.e. System A's key) to this file?

Would Git recognize any file I created without any command specifying so??

*And where does the ~/.ssh/config file come into all of this?*

We've got msysgit installed on all of our systems. Installing any other software isn't really possible right now because we need to take special permissions for that in our environment.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=setting+up+ssh+keys

Comment: This would allow other users to logon as you, which seems like a really bad idea. Is there are reason why you're not allowing them to logon as themselves?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a file called `authorized_keys` and add user B's public key to this file (newline separated).

Basically:

```
cat userb.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

`userb.pub` (if it was created correctly) should already be properly formatted.

Comment: Will I need to edit any file like config on user B's system before this starts working?

Comment: You shouldn't need to. `ssh-keygen` should be enough.